# Java: is it possible to create a class with "variable" fields?

Tags: java

Thanks for your help.

I have the following situation:

I have a Class that contains the response from an API:

```
public class EventsResponse extends ApiResponse {

  public JSONArray response;

  public EventsResponse(Boolean success,RequestHandle requesthandle, JSONArray responsefromapi) {
    super(success, requesthandle);
    if(responsefromapi!=null)this.response=responsefromapi;
    else response=null;
  }
  public EventsResponse(Boolean success,RequestHandle requesthandle, JSONObject responsefromapi) {
    super(success, requesthandle);
    if(responsefromapi!=null)this.response=responsefromapi;
    else response=null;
  }
}
```

As you can see something is not working here:

if `responsefromapi` is a `JSONObject` I try to assign it to a `response` which is a `JSONArray` obviously does not work...

**What I would like to do is:**

to assign that `responsefromapi` to `response`and have `response` to be a `JSONObject` or a `JSONArray` depending on what is `responsefromapi`.

So that I can use a sigle Class `EventsResponse` to handle both situations and  `EventsResponse`will contain a `response` which is `JSONObject` or a `JSONArray` depending on the situation.

Please is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Everything is possible but what would you then plan to do with the object that you don't know the exact type of?

Comment: @biziclop I could check what kind of object do I get back and act accordingly, that is the idea...

Comment: Does your responsefromapi JSONObject contain a key whose value is an array, and you want that array to be stored into JSONArray response.?

Comment: @Amal thanks for your comment Amal, but that is not what I would like to do, I would like to do strictly what is in the question ;-)

Comment: Do you want to write a single class or use a single object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Generics:

```
public class EventsResponse<K> extends ApiResponse {
    public K response;
    public EventsResponse(Boolean success, RequestHandle requesthandle, K responsefromapi) {
        super(success, requesthandle);
        response = responsefromapi;
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
new EventResponse<JSONObject>(...);
```

AND

```
new EventResponse<JSONArray>(...);
```

Comment: You are quite right Peter, I edited the question, thanks

Comment: @LisaAnne I think he was referring to the `else response = null;` part which is superfluous. Response is already `null`. Still your edit is correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Is not very elegant but you could try using `Object` common superclass to reference your response:

```
public Object response;
...
...
public EventsResponse(Boolean success,RequestHandle requesthandle, JSONArray responsefromapi) {
    super(success, requesthandle);
    if(response!=null)this.response= (Object)responsefromapi;
    else response=null;
}
```

You will need Java's reflection to use the referenced object later in your code:

```
if(response.getClass().equals(JSONArray.class)) {
  ...
  ...
  JSONArray responseAsJSONArray = (JSONArray)response;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@LisaAnne. My understanding is given below :-

1. You have two scenarios out of which, one will return the JsonArray type and other will return JSONObject type.
2. To ensure that the implementation is clean and written in the same class, you have created two overloaded constructors to fetch the response type from the class which is calling this EventsResponse Class.
3. The problem however seems to be in the assignment of the responseFromApi (JSONObject or JSONArray depending on the constructor used) to the JSONArray response property, as a direct cast from the Object to JSONArray is not present.

**Details :-**
As per my understanding, we use JSONObject to store and pass a value of a JSON String something like `{name:"LisaAnne", address:"xyz", responseArray:[{name1:"n1"},{name1:"n2"}]}.`
JSONObject contains key value pairs Whereas,
JSONArray contains an ordered pair. If you fetch the value of responseArray into a JSONArray type of object, you will be successful.

to fetch an array from the response the following type of statement should work.

```
JSONArray response= bigDataResponse.getJSONArray("responseArray");
```

***Therefore, a direct cast from the JSONObject to a JSONArray will not be possible. You will have to get the key that contains the array and use the statement given above to fetch it.***

I'll be able to give you a better solution if you can give me the response structures received in the  `JSONObject responsefromapi` and `JSONArray responsefromapi`

Hope this helps.